# How to relate audio data to time

Tags: c#, audio, mp3, naudio

Lets say I would like to read 1 millisecond of sound data from an Mp3 file and present it. Something like this:

```
var stream = NAudio.WaveStream.Mp3FileReader(filename);
int intervalInMilliseconds = someInterval;
int bytesPerInterval = ???;
for(int i = 0; i < bytesPerInterval;i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine(stream.GetByte());
}
```

What do I need to do to solve for bytesPerInterval? Is this even possible to do accurately? (Note:NAudio is not a requirement here, just what I am currently using.)

Or if I have a byte index, is it possible to determine what point in time that byte would be played (relative to time 00:00:0000)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't read 1 millisecond of audio data from MP3 directly.  MP3 works in the frequency domain with fixed size time slices.  A typical slice is around 13 milliseconds.

To get accurate timing, you need to convert your audio back to samples in the time domain.  CD-quality audio is sampled 44,100 times per second with 16-bit PCM samples.  Calculating the raw size in bytes for this data is simple:

```
sampleCount * bytesPerSample * channels
```

Also, one millisecond of audio doesn't evenly divide into 44.1kHz, so you will need to pick timing that does.

Comment: Could you give an example in code of reading a time slice that does evenly divide? Not sure how to define sampleCount or bytesPerSample.

Comment: @Colton What are you trying to do?  If there is a sample every 1/44,100th of a second, then pick a spot that is some multiple of that.  Bytes per sample is the bit depth.  If you have 16-bit samples, then you have 2 bytes per sample.  Again though, none of this has anything to do with MP3.  You can only slice MP3 up at frame boundaries, and even then you have to deal with the bit reservoir which can smear data up to a couple frames away from the frame you're trying to play back.

Comment: Basically, I'm just trying to understand how audio data works from this post. My end goal is to calculate the amplitude of a sound wave for a specified interval, specified point, etc. (Not sure which technique will be the most useful yet), and then applying AI techniques on this data. Similar to what an audio visualizer does, but I need the bytes, not the visual. I need to be able to to say "At 1.5s, the amplitude was x" and the amplitude would be a sum of the data between the [1.5-interval, 1.5]...I think.

Comment: @Colton Alright, so drop MP3 completely as that isn't relevant to your question at all.  Back in the time-domain world with PCM samples...  Those sample values **are** the amplitude values quantized for the point in time for which the sample was taken.  There are many different ways to store these samples.... different endianness, intereleaving, floating point, etc., but at the end of the day it's all amplitude.

Comment: Right, but I need to know the point in time that the amplitude is played. So from the pcm data, if I want to get all the bytes between time 0s and time 1s, I should read 44,100 units of data? I was hoping for an example stemming from mp3 (i.e. show whatever I need to retrieve the pcm data too). I am not exactly audio savvy, so I'm not sure if what I am saying makes much sense.

Comment: If you have a raw audio file (no headers or anything) with a single channel (mono, not stereo) sampled at 44.1kHz 16 bit, then you would read 88,200 bytes per second of data.  I haven't used NAudio in years so I can't provide a good example for you.  In any case, you'll need to run that file through a codec to get PCM samples back.  Perhaps NAudio supports that... I don't remember off the top of my head.