# How to interpret raw pcm data from an MP3 file

Tags: c#, audio, mp3

I am using NAudio to retrieve the raw pcm data from an MP3 file. Then I need to read this data at set intervals (time based).

However, I'm having a hard time understanding how to interpret this data. For example, if the MP3 was stereo vs mono vs anything else, how should I read the data? How do I even check if the MP3 was stereo or mono? What other factors can change how I need to read the data?

I'm hoping for sample code here, but any help is appreciated.

```
NAudio.Wave.WaveStream pcm = NAudio.Wave.WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(new NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader(mp3FilePath));
int someInterval = 88200;//~1 second depending on the file specs
byte[] buffer = new byte[someInterval];
int current = 0;
int ret = 0;
do
{
     ret = pcm.Read(buffer, current, someInterval);

     //do something

     current += someInterval;
} while (ret != -1);
```

Context from a previous question:([How to relate audio data to time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28888838/how-to-relate-audio-data-to-time))

```
If you have a raw audio file (no headers or anything) with a single channel (mono, not stereo) sampled at 44.1kHz 16 bit, then you would read 88,200 bytes per second of data [to read 1 second of audio data].
```

How do I detect the channels? Then how do I read the pcm data to match it?

Comment: does NAudio have any support doc for their .net api ?

Comment: Nothing I could find was relative to this. It seems that NAudio is focused on playback more than anything. I will keep looking. (Mind you, if I did see something useful I probably wouldn't know. I really have no clue what I'm talking about when it comes to audio.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the format from `pcm.WaveFormat` from which you can find channel count, number of channels, average bytes per second, etc...

```
NAudio.Wave.WaveStream pcm = NAudio.Wave.WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(new NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader(mp3FilePath));
int someInterval = pcm.WaveFormat.Channels * pcm.WaveFormat.SampleRate * pcm.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample/8;
```

From there you'll need to decode the bytes into ints or floats. There are a lot of answers on SO addressing that question.

Comment: Awesome. So is "someInterval" still a unit of time here? If so, what is it (per ms, per second, etc)? If not, how can I then determine how to read exactly 1 second of data (or any arbitrary interval)?

Comment: Yes, it's 1 seconds worth of bytes.  samples/sec * byts/sample = bytes/sec. multiply times the # of channels of coarse which is a scalar. the final answer you can multiply by the seconds as a double and truncate.  so for half a divide the result by 2.